# CS50 Readability python, false output

Tags: python, cs50

````
```
from cs50 import get_string

text = get_string("Text: ") 
letters = sentences = 0
words = 1

for i in text:
    if i.isalpha():
        letters += 1
    if i.isspace():
        words += 1
    if i in ['!', '.', '?']:
        sentences += 1
                       
L = (letters / words) * 100
S = (sentences / words) * 100
index = round(0.0588 * L - 0.0296 * S - 15.8)
if index < 1:
    print("Before Grade 1")
elif index >= 16:
    print("Grade 16+")
else:
    print(f"Grade {index}")
```
````

I'm working on a task of cs50 to make readability in python, but the answer is always not the same as what is written in the manual guide in cs50 website. for example, for input;

> Text: Congratulations! Today is your day. You're off to Great Places!
> You're off and away!

it should print "Grade 3" but instead my code print "Grade 11", I think my code is fine, and the formula I use is in accordance with the guidelines on the website. i tried various solutions related to this on stackoverflow and still didn't get the right answer, what did I do wrong?

Comment: What is the value your code computes for `L` and for `S`? Does that agree with what you expect? Also, have you tried talking to the professor about this?

Comment: Why not post the question to https://cs50.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Check the index equation against the spec. There is a mistake.

Comment: Oh yes, found it!  thank you so much for reminding me

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

[image]

P.S. I get an error when I tried to put the python code in here, that's why I sent a photo!

Comment: @appolloWayne please share code instead on the image see the details here [How to insert code properly on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30699614)